# Appending JS obj values into dynamically-created modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, for-loop

I have a JS object that contains a bunch of training courses: Each category has multiple training courses and each course belongs to one category.

I've been able to render each category's description and title into a modal. For instance, by clicking on the Animals div a modal titled "Animals" and its description shows up, and clicking on a different div loads different info.

I'm trying to load each of the training courses into each modal but based on how I've rendered each category div I've run into problems, namely the fact that the category's description and title come from *one* JS object (`_categories`) and the training courses come from a *separate* JS object (`_library`).

Based on what I've done below with `catBoxElems +=`, is it possible to append each training course into each modal? Or would I have to append the courses outside of the loop?

```
loadCategories(){

        let categs = _categories,
            libCrs = _library

        console.log(libCrs);

      // libCrs[i].Title only shows the first course in the first category div, the second course in the second category div, etc.
            let catBoxElems = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
                    catBoxElems += 
                    "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'data-target='#modal-id' data-toggle='modal' data-desc='" + categs[i].Description + "'data-title='" + categs[i].Title + "'data-crs='" + libCrs[i].Title + "'>" + catPic + "<br>" + categs[i].Title + "</div>";
                } 

           $(document).find("#modal-id").off("shown.bs.modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
                $(document).find(".modal-title").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("title"));
                $(document).find(".category-desc").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("desc"));
                $(document).find(".training-titles-ul").html($(e.relatedTarget).data("crs"));
            }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
                $(document).find(".modal-title").html("");
            });

      let container = document.querySelector("div.top-training");
        container.innerHTML = catBoxElems;
        console.log(container);

}
```

#### console:

> [object Array]      [Object {...}, Object {...},...etc
>       0
>          Title          "Brooklyn"

#### Modal:

```
     <div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-backdrop">
          <div class="modal-content"> 

            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span class="x-close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </a>

            <div class="modal-img"></div>

            <div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="category-desc"></div>
              <div class="training-titles">
                <ul class="training-titles-ul">

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div> <!-- modal-content -->
        </div> <!-- modal-backdrop -->
```

Comment: Why not having modal code and each time dynamically assign category details?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou do you mean setting `data-attributes` for the modal? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: You will have modal html code and before show assign the text that you want.

Comment: do you want each time to create new modal code? Or you want to have one modal and each time change the text?

Comment: I'd rather have just one modal and the text changes each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have added modal code and each time before show `show.bs.modal`, the text is changing.

Also, i have added a counter `i` so when modal hides `hide.bs.modal` is incrementing to display the next elements of the key-value array.

Check my example.

```js
  var i=0;
      $(document).ready(function(){
     
     $("#btn1").click(function(){
     
     var myArray = { 0:{description:'desc1' , title: 'title 1'},1:{description:'desc 2' , title: 'title 2'} };
     
     $("#exampleModal").on("show.bs.modal",function(){
        $("#exampleModal").find('.modal-body').html("<p>"+myArray[i].description+"</p>");
     $("#exampleModal").find('.modal-title').text(myArray[i].title);
     });
     
     $("#exampleModal").on("hide.bs.modal",function(){ i++; if(i == Object.keys(myArray).length){ $('#btn1').attr('disabled','disabled'); } });
     
     $("#exampleModal").modal();
     
  });
   });
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Default text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```